# jquery: Change the background-colour of a column if its header has a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery that I'm trying to use to change the background colour of a column where its header has a class.

So for example:

```
$('th').each(function (i) {

            if ($(this).hasClass('headerSortUp') || $(this).hasClass('headerSortDown')) {
                sortIndex = $(this).index();
            }
            $('tr').each(function () {
                $('td:eq(' + sortIndex + ')').css('background-color', 'orange');
            });

        });
```

So if I had a table like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th class="headerSortDown">Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So in this example the whole first column should have a bg of orange. However it's not working... Any ideas what I have done wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to specify the context

```
$('td:eq(' + sortIndex + ')', this).css('background-color', 'orange');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `sortIndex = $(this).index();` to `sortIndex =i;` and
 `$('td:eq(' + sortIndex + ')').css('background-color', 'orange');` to

`$('td:eq(' + sortIndex + ')',$(this)).css('background-color', 'orange');` to select td 's withing the tr

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to iterate over the `<th>` elements - a selector can pick out just the ones with the right classes.

You can then use `.index()` to find their column value, and `:nth-child()` to select every `<td>` in that column in one go:

```
$('.headerSortUp, .headerSortDown').each(function() {
    var n = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('td:nth-child(' + n + ')').css('background-color', 'orange');
});
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jNsF4/

[I note also that the original code has a logic error - the code to change the colours should be inside the `if { ... }` block, not outside it].

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better selector that causes lesser iterations

```
var sortIndex;

$('th').each(function (i) {

            if ($(this).hasClass('headerSortUp') || $(this).hasClass('headerSortDown')) {
                sortIndex = $(this).index();
            }
    });


$('td:nth-child(' +sortIndex+1+')').css('background-color', 'orange');
```

You can check the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ryan_s/nZr9G/